# Existence of nonzero trace commutator in infinite dimensional Hilbert space

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be an infinite dimensional Hilbert space. Is it true that we can always find two (continuous) linear operators $A, B: H \to H$ such that $AB, BA$ are of trace class, or at least $[A, B] = AB - BA$ is, such that $\mathrm{Tr}([A, B]) \neq 0$?

This question originated from the observation $[\partial, x] =1$ and that can be used to show that $\mathbb{C}[x]$ is infinite dimensional as a vector space since $\mathrm{Tr}([A, B]) = 0$ for finite dimensional vector spaces (although we can show it directly). In some sense, I wonder about the converse of this statement. Maybe there’s nothing to do with Hilbert space, but we can restrict to that case anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer provides an example of two operators $A,B$ such that $AB-BA$ is in the trace class and ${\rm Tr}\,(AB-BA)\neq 0.$

Let $\{e_n\}_{n=0}^\infty $ denote an orthonormal basis in $\mathcal{H}$. Let $Ae_n=e_{n+1}.$ Then $A^*e_0=0$ and $A^*e_n=e_{n-1}.$ We get $A^*A=I$ and $AA^*= I-P_0$, where $P_0$ is the orthogonal projection onto $\mathbb{C}e_0.$ Hence $A^*A-AA^*=P_0$ and ${\rm Tr}\,(A^*A-AA^*)=1.$

If $\mathcal{H}$ is not separable we can decompose the space as $\mathcal{H}= \mathcal{H}_1\oplus \mathcal{H}_2,$ where $\mathcal{H}_1$ has a countable orthonormal basis. Then we define $A$  acting on $\mathcal{H}_1$ as above and acting  on $\mathcal{H}_2$  as the identity operator. Then ${\rm Tr}\,(A^*A-AA^*)=1.$

Comment: Thanks, after reading your answer, I just realized that the example I proposed is quite similar to your more general answer. (Maybe taking $e_n = x^n$ and $Av =xv$ would work for suitable inner product...)

Comment: Consider the space $H^2(\mathbb{T})$ consisting of square integrable functions on the unit circle, whose negative Fourier coefficients vanish. Then $\{z^n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ form an orthonormal basis. The operator $(Af)(z)=zf(z),$ $z\in \mathbb{T},$ is unitarily equivalent to $A$ in my answer and satisfies $Az^n=z^{n+1}.$ I am very curious whether it is possible to construct an example where $AB$ is of trace class, or at least compact.